# sikuli classpath UnsatisfiedLinkError no opencv_core with macosx intellij Junit

Tags: java, opencv, classpath, sikuli, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I have done previous searches trying to find an answer to this however my attempts failed so far.  I think the error is quite simple its just not loading the classes.

**I am running MacOSX 10 with intellij.  I am using it with Junit Spring and Maven & Junit.**

I followed the maven dependencies found  [mvnrepository.com - sikuli-api 1.2.0](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.sikuli/sikuli-api/1.2.0) so I was thinking that if the dependencies are added to the pom then all files should be in my class path?  So I don't understand why its not working?

This [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9668552/sikuli-unsatisfiedlinkerror-when-using-sikuli-script-jar) looks close to mine - but its for windows im on a mac.  However by using maven I should not need to add it to the class path??  or am I missing something.  This [similar unanswered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26799471/javacv-yosemite-eclipse-project-not-running-java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror) question also looks similar uses mac like mine

**POM Dependencies added**

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.sikuli</groupId>
        <artifactId>sikuli-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.sikuli</groupId>
        <artifactId>sikuli-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>14.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bytedeco</groupId>
        <artifactId>javacpp</artifactId>
        <version>0.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets</groupId>
        <artifactId>opencv</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.9-0.9</version>
        <classifier>macosx-x86_64</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.piccolo2d</groupId>
        <artifactId>piccolo2d-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.piccolo2d</groupId>
        <artifactId>piccolo2d-extras</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

**My test**

```
static {
    System.setProperty("platform.dependency", "macosx-x86_64");
    //System.setProperty("platform.dependency", "1");  // tried this also
}

@Test
public void testOne() throws Exception {

    File file = new File(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("camera_icon.png").getFile());

    browse(new URL("http://code.google.com"));

    ScreenRegion s = new DesktopScreenRegion();
    Target target = new ColorImageTarget(file);

    // ** Fails here  **
    ScreenRegion r = s.find(target); 
    ....
```

**The Error - ClassLoader**

I followed the debugger and it fails on the class loader for open_core -- see screenshot

[image]

**Update**

I added the POM classifier per Samuel answer below.  I also tried [setting the system property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11306951/how-to-set-environment-variable-or-system-property-in-spring-tests). still getting the same error.

Also noticed the following error - I have tried to cut it down as much as possible.

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /private/var/folders/qp/.../libjniopencv_core.dylib: dlopen(/private/var/....../libjniopencv_core.dylib, 1): Library not loaded: @rpath/libopencv_core.2.4.dylib
  Referenced from: /private/var/.......libjniopencv_core.dylib
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /private/va.....77/./libopencv_core.2.4.dylib: malformed mach-o image: load command #12 length (0) too small in /private/var/fo......./libopencv_core.2.4.dylib  t java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For my work around I install opencv via homebrew.  Open terminal and type the following.

`brew tap homebrew/science`

brew info opencv

`brew install opencv`

This allowed my POM to be much smaller

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>sikuliTest</groupId>
    <artifactId>sikuliTest</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.sikuli</groupId>
        <artifactId>sikuli-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

</project>
```

**The test**

```
@Test
public void testOne() throws IOException {

    File file = new File(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("image_to_click.jpeg").getFile());
    browse(new URL("http://code.google.com"));

    // click image that looks like image_to_click.jpeg
    ScreenRegion s = new DesktopScreenRegion(1);
    ScreenRegion s1 = s.find(new ImageTarget(file));
    Mouse mouse = new DesktopMouse();
    mouse.click(s1.getCenter());

    // take a screenshot and save it
    BufferedImage img = s.capture();
    File outputfile = new File("screenshot_image.jpg");
    ImageIO.write(img, "jpg", outputfile);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The answer is basically in the [README.md file](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp-presets/), but I'll spell it out here. You will need to set either the `platform.dependency` system property to the desired platform, for example, `macosx-x86_64`, or to `true` the `platform.dependencies` one, to get dependencies for all platforms. I'm not sure how we're supposed to set that with JUnit Spring (it should be in the docs), but even that doesn't work with SBT anyway, so to work around these cases we can add the platform-specific dependencies manually. Since you're running on Mac OS X and interested in using OpenCV 2.4.9, adding this additional dependency to your `pom.xml` file should work:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets</groupId>
    <artifactId>opencv</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.9-0.9</version>
    <classifier>macosx-x86_64</classifier>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I tried your suggestions.  I think you are on the right track.  However its still not fixed it. I updated the question with suggested actions.  What is SBT?

Comment: @Robbo_UK  That error's been fixed in later versions. Try again with 0.11. SBT is a build tool for Scala.

Comment: I tried 0.11 and that breaks sikuli.  It has a dependency for 0.9.  I gave +1 as it may help others who come across it.